# Probability that the discriminant of a quadratic field is divisible by a given prime number $p.$

Tags: number-theory, prime-numbers, algebraic-number-theory

Find the probability that the discriminant $D$ of a quadratic field $\mathbb{Q}(\sqrt{d})$ is divisible by a given prime number $p$ (beware: the result is not what you may expect.)

This is an exercise from Cohen's Computational Algebraic Number Theory. I have no idea how to go about it. All I know is that 
$$ 
D = \begin{cases}
d & d\equiv 1 \mod{4}      \\
4d &  d\equiv 2,3\mod{4} 
\end{cases}
$$
How can I make connection whether $D$ is divisible by a given $p.$ I will appreciate any help.

I did some computations for this on sage for the first $10339$ discriminants.  According to results obtained the probability should be $\frac{1}{p+1}$ for odd prime $p.$ For probability i used 
$$ \text{Prob}_p = \frac{\text{Number of discriminant divisible by}~p}{\text{Total number of discriminants}}$$
$$
\begin{array}{l l}
p & \frac{1}{p+1} & Prob_p \\
\hline
 2 &     0.33333 &     0.66670   \\
 3 &     0.25000 &     0.24993   \\
 5 &     0.16667 &     0.16684   \\
 7 &     0.12500 &     0.12496   \\
 11 &     0.083333 &     0.083567   \\
 13 &     0.071429 &     0.071767   \\
 17 &     0.055556 &     0.055615   \\
 19 &     0.050000 &     0.049715   \\
 23 &     0.041667 &     0.041687   \\
 29 &     0.033333 &     0.033272   \\
 31 &     0.031250 &     0.031241   \\
 37 &     0.026316 &     0.026405   \\
 41 &     0.023810 &     0.023697   \\
 43 &     0.022727 &     0.022633   \\
 47 &     0.020833 &     0.020602   \\
 53 &     0.018519 &     0.018474   \\
 59 &     0.016667 &     0.016829   \\
 61 &     0.016129 &     0.016249   \\
 67 &     0.014706 &     0.014702   \\
 71 &     0.013889 &     0.014121   \\
\hline
\end{array}
$$

I tried to prove this as follows:
For odd prime $p,$ the discriminant $D$ is divisible by $p$ if and only if $p\mid d.$ We know that $d$ is square-free and number of square-free integers up-to $x$ is 
$$ \approx  x \prod_{p} \left(1-\frac{1}{p^2}\right) $$
Somehow i need to modify this to count the number that are divisible by $p$
for separate cases when $d\equiv 1\pmod{4}$ and $d\equiv 2,3\pmod{4}.$
I am not able to make any further progress.

Comment: Does "Cohen" explain what he/she means by probability? In what probability space? This sounds to me like a question that stretches the definition of "probability."

Comment: No he does not explain any thing..

Comment: The part about when does $p$ divide $D$ - that's easy. If $p=2$ then $p$ does not divide $D = d$ when $d \equiv 1 \mod 4$, and otherwise $p$ divides $D = 4d$. If $p$ is an odd prime, then $p$ divides $D$ if and only if it divides $d$. However, this DOES NOT MEAN that there is some sort of "probability" - equal to 0.75 when $p=2$ and equal to $\frac 1 p$ when $p$ is odd. The statement "the probability that an integer is even is 0.5" is neither true nor false; it is UNDEFINED. What "probability"? In what probability space?

Comment: The answer is $1/(p+1).$

Comment: What is that, an asymptotic frequency? It is not a PROBABILITY!

Comment: Note that $\prod_{p}^{}\bigg(1-\dfrac{1}{p^2}\bigg)=\dfrac{1}{\zeta(2)}=\dfrac{6}{\pi^2}$. http://mathworld.wolfram.com/PrimeProducts.html